# Building an SQL query for GROUP_CONCAT-ing multiple one/many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, many-to-many, group-concat

I have four tables, `person`, `email`, `organ` and `person_organ` and:

- `person` and `email` has one-to-many relation;
- `person` and `organ` has many-to-many relation through `person_organ`.

Question, how to I write a query so I have a set with columns `full name`, `all email` and `all organ` for persons in a particular organ?

This is as far as I get, using `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine emails grouped by person:

```sql
select person.id as 'ID', 
       organ.short_name as 'Organ', 
       CONCAT ( person.first_name, ' ', person.last_name) as 'Full Name', 
       GROUP_CONCAT(email.email SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Emails'
    from person 
  left join person_organ on person.id = person_organ.person_id 
  join organ on organ.id = person_organ.organ_id
  join email on email.person_id = person.id
  where person_organ.organ_id = 1
  group by person.id;
```

What can I add to the above query so that another column is added that shows all the groups that this person belongs to?

What I have so far:

```
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+
| ID | Organ | Full Name    | Emails                     |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | SC    | John Doe     | john@doe.me, jdoe@mail.org |
|  2 | SC    | Richard Rowe | rowe@mail.us               |
|  3 | SC    | San Zhang    | zhangsan@mail.cn           |
|  4 | SC    | Taro Yamada  | yamada@mail.jp             |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

What I want, is to have the `Organs` as an additional column to the above result set, in addition to the *singular* `Organ` field:

```
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
| ID | Organ | Full Name    | Emails                     | Organs     |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
|  1 | SC    | John Doe     | john@doe.me, jdoe@mail.org | SC, EC     |
|  2 | SC    | Richard Rowe | rowe@mail.us               | SC, EC, HR |
|  3 | SC    | San Zhang    | zhangsan@mail.cn           | SC, HR     |
|  4 | SC    | Taro Yamada  | yamada@mail.jp             | SC, EC, HR |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
```

Thank you very much for your answer! I am quite new to making real applications and I feel that this should be quite a common task. Any help on pointing to the right resources is much welcome!

-- update: SQLfiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc08de/40

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc08de/14/0 I am not much aware of the syntax in MySQL but I have tried this and got to this result. The id that is 1 has duplicates. Maybe because of some syntax. just have a look at it
Have got the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get those in ONE result set? i.e. to also include the columns for [names] and  [multiple emails].

Comment: Add the
CONCAT ( person.first_name, ' ', person.last_name) as 'Full Name', GROUP_CONCAT(email.email SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Emails'
from your code after my code for Organs. And ya even then its throwing same emails multiple times just like the organs fields. (I am not very aware of the syntax so correct it and you will get the right answer)

Comment: hmm.... now both columns contain duplicates: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc08de/23

Comment: You can actually achieve the desired result using sub query but I am unaware of the syntax used for sub query.

Comment: Hi @shashank-raj-chavan, I added distinct to the group_concat, and it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc08de/37, -- update: but not when I need to show that for a particular group, i.e. when organ.id =1.: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc08de/40

Comment: Cool! :) If you feel the answer has helped please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi, @shashank-raj-chavan, still, it's not quite answering the original question.. please see my last comment above... Thanks.